# Trouble accessing images uploaded in back-end project

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, file-upload, path

I am trying to access images stored in an /uploads/ folder in my front-end app.

I get a 404 for both http://localhost:4200/uploads/a.jpg and http://localhost:4200/StaticFiles/a.jpg. I need the image's path to display it in a gallery.

I tried using the full path of the image ("D:/blabla/uploads/a.jpg"), but it seems that is restricted. Then I used the code below to provide from the back-end a path to my uploads folder, but I still get 404.

My back-end and front-end projects are in different folders, and my front-end sends requests to back-end's port.

Back-end running latest .net core, front-end is Angular 8.

This is how I serve the static files:

```cs
var aux = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "uploads");

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(aux),
        RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
    }
);
```

This is how I upload the image. The code works and uploads images in the /uploads folder, inside the project.

```cs
var uploadFilesPath = Path.Combine(_host.ContentRootPath, "uploads");

if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFilesPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFilesPath);

    foreach (var file in fileData)
        {
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFilesPath, fileName);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }

            var propToAddImageTo = _propManager.GetById(id);

            _propManager.AddImage(propToAddImageTo, filePath);
        }
```

When I try to set a simple `<img src="localhost:4200/uploads/a.jpg">` or `<img src="localhost:4200/StaticFiles/a.jpg">`, the request on the network tab from Mozilla's Developer Tools says 404.

Comment: Are you sure that `_host.ContentRootPath` and `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` refer to the same place? The StaticFiles middleware might be serving from a different location than you are expecting.

Comment: this was it! because the projects were in two different folders, staticfiles was serving from localhost:2121 and i was requesting :4200.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I posted it as an answer. Feel free to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for `_host.ContentRootPath` is equal to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, but only if you are using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

> `CreateDefaultBuilder` performs the following tasks:
>
> - ...
> - Sets the content root to the path returned by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`.

Your code assumes `ContentRootPath` is *always* the same as `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`, but that won't always be true. If you are not using `CreateDefaultBuilder`, or your code is split across multiple projects (as you mentioned in your comment), they won't point to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Below codes works for me :

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"uploads")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")
});
app.UseMvc();
```

It needs the `uploads` folder should exist in root directory , otherwise it will throw error . Suppose the structure is ApplicationName/uploads/a.jpg , you can use like :

`<img src="http://localhost:xxxx/StaticFiles/a.jpg">`

To save images on server side , you could find the path by :

```
var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "uploads");
```